# A very long message for LUIS dialog resets dialog state

Tags: botframework

Using bot framework emulator v.3.5.36, if a user sends long text (about 1K characters), emulator silently resets dialog stack back to root dialog, without any errors or warnings. (see the screenshot below.)

Is there a declared message limit for bot framework?

Is there a way for bot to handle such situations and warn user instead of this silent something?

[image]

There is nothing really specific about the code at all:

```
[LuisModel("{GUID}", "{CODE}", LuisApiVersion.V2, domain: "westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com", threshold: 0.5)]
[Serializable]
public class LuisSearchDialog2 : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    } 
}
```

Comment: It seems that you forward message to a QnA dialog from root dialog, could you share the relevant code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Without code it is difficult to help you

Comment: @NicolasR right. I've made some additional debugging, and the problem seems to be located in LuisDialog - when an exception results from invoking LUIS API, it is not reported via usual "My bot is having an issue"...

Comment: And so? Next step is to bring some code or this question is useless, thanks

Comment: @NicolasR I've added the code - as I said it's rather simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that base [LuisDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs) doens't handle failed API requests (in case if query is too long, it returns 414 code). So the simplest way to handle such errors is to override MessageReceived as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class LuisSearchDialog2 : LuisDialog<object>
{
    protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
    {
        try
        {
            await base.MessageReceived(context, activity);
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException e)
        {
            // Handle error here
            //await context.PostAsync("Error: " + e.ToString());
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to **check the length** of your message in the **MessageController** and decide whether you want to process it or not.

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
 {
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl);
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        if (activity.Text != null && activity.Text.Length > 200)
        {
                var errorReply = activity.CreateReply();
                errorReply.Text = "Well well, that is too much of data. How about keeping it simple? How can I help you?";
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(errorReply);
        }
        else
        {

               await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, that's a simple approach... It would be better to find the root cause instead

Comment: Totally agree on that :)